# Airflow DAG not triggered

Tags: python, airflow

I'm unable to run a DAG as scheduled, only by triggering it manually.
I've set start_date as days_ago(1) and also as a specific date - datetime(2021, 06, 19).
schedule_interval is set to a specific time '55 11 * * 0' but when the time comes the DAG still not been triggered.
I've tried to delete the python file completely and recreating a new one with a different name- still no trigger.

please help, any lead will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Eran

Comment: Please post your dag code and what airflow version you are working with

Comment: default_args = {

    'owner': 'eranh',

    'retries': 3,

    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),

    'email_on_failure': True,

    'email_on_retry': True
}
 

with DAG('disabled_accounts', 

         default_args=default_args,

         start_date=datetime(2021, 6, 19),  

         schedule_interval='55 11 * * 0', 

         catchup=True 
         ) as dag:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow doesn't schedule DAGs like cron job.
Airflow calculates `start_date+schedule_interval` and execute the task at the **end** of the interval. so when you set

```
start_date = datetime(2021, 06, 19)
schedule_interval='55 11 * * 0'
```

the first run will not start at `2021-06-20` (Sunday) as you may expect.

If you wanted your DAG to execute weekly on Sundays and the first run to be on `2021-06-20` you should set:

```
start_date = datetime(2021, 06, 13)
schedule_interval='55 11 * * 0'
```

Comment: Hi Elad, Thanks for you answer.
I've changed the start date to last week as suggested but still the same, DAG not been triggered.

Comment: Then you have some other problem. Edit the answer with your dag code and your scheduler logs.

Comment: I don't know what I did differently but I've setup the start interval to 11:10 and it ran on 14:10 right now (I don't care about the UTC difference it is not the issue).
I have this DAG written for almost 3 weeks now and it is the first time it has triggered.
Thanks Elad for your help!

Comment: The default (if not changed is UTC). You can write timezone aware dags if that is what you want.

Comment: I had the DAG with interval of every sunday morning and start time was days_ago(1) but the DAG wouldn't trigger for weeks.
The only thing I did today is to completely delete the file and create a new one with a different DAG name, maybe it helped I don't know.

Comment: @EranHc, Did the issue resolve for you? If Yes, what were the steps taken